# Hosmer-Lemeshow Goodness of Fit (GOF) Test

Tags: r, survival-analysis, goodness-of-fit

I want to apply a HL GoF test to my survival analysis.

The test description can be found [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ResourceSelection/docs/hoslem.test):

Taking some readily available data we can plot the cdf with 95% CI

```
library(survival)
library(ResourceSelection)
data(ovarian)

s <- Surv(ovarian$futime, ovarian$fustat)
sWei <- survreg(s ~ age,dist='weibull',data=ovarian)

probs <- seq(0.001,0.999,0.001)
pred <- predict(sWei,type="uquantile",p=probs,se.fit=TRUE)
val <- cbind(pred$fit[1,],pred$fit[1,]-1.96*pred$se.fit[1,],pred$fit[1,]+1.96*pred$se.fit[1,])
val <- exp(val)
# cumulative density function 
plot(val[,1], probs)
lines(val[,2], probs, col='red')
lines(val[,3], probs, col='red')
```

But we want to run a HL GoF test to assess if a Weibull distribution was incorrect.

Thus:

```
hoslem(x,y)
x = vector of observations
y = fitted probabilities
```

I try, but am not correct. Can someone guide me towards the correct fitted probabilities, they need to be the same length of the observations

```
hl <- hoslem.test(ovarian$fustat, val[,1], g=10)
```

Comment: I guess it should be something along `hoslem.test(ovarian$fustat, pred(sWei), g=10)` or `hoslem.test(ovarian$fustat, pred$fit[,n], g=10)`.

Comment: I was more thinking `predict(sWei, newdata=list(ovarian$age))`might be along the lines